# FlatUI switch and angularjs view

Tags: jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

i'm using FlatUI kit, i need use the switch (checkbox) control of the kit. It works in my angular template file (index.html), but if i put the same code into one view (loaded in the ng-view statement of the template) it doesn't work. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Are you putting the code in the View?  Setup a plnkr.co or jsfiddle.net to demonstrate the issue

Answer (score 0):

i solved digging into the internet searching for other things, the solution can be one of theese adapted to the flatui controls. the code must be launched inside the controller or with a directive

Controller
http://plnkr.co/edit/PDX500tp5QgcjIMIbig1?p=preview

Directive
http://plnkr.co/edit/LVKHkmNrTS2Ki7uP8Hgj?p=preview

sample for my controller taken from the application.js of the FlatUI kit

```
$("[data-toggle='switch']").wrap('<div class="switch" />').parent().bootstrapSwitch();
```

Comment: i can do the same with checkbox, but i cannot "intercept" the checkbox "checked" status, how can i bind the angularjs model to the checkbox status?